# How to define the schema explicitly for a node-postgres pool

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am using a nodepostgres pool to query a database which has a custom schema.

There are 2 ways to handle this:

1. All the queries need to be specialized with the schema like `customSchema.tablename`.
2. Make this query before other queries:
   `pool.query(SET search_path TO ${params["db_schema"]}, public`);

I have two problems with these approaches:

1. I need to selectively connect to two DBs. One DB has a custom schema, and the other does not. So I cannot use method #1.
2. When using a query approach to set the seach_path, it works for a few queries, and then gives error saying it cannot find the table. I believe this is because the pool connections timeout or something similar.

So, is there a way I can define the schema is a more consistent way?

Answer (score 1):

This depends a bit on how you connect, but if you use a consistent user, you can run:

```
ALTER USER SET search_path TO your_schema, public;
```

Then, whenever the user connects, that user will have that search_path set by default.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know exactly what do you mean in your 1. problem:

> need to selectively connect to two DBs. One DB has a custom schema, and the other does not

Maybe this [solution](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1123#issuecomment-557545445) can help you.

You can also find it in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59887536/6496006
(the 2. part is relevant)