# Sanitizing user inputs when the user input is a schema name in node postgres

Tags: node.js, node-postgres, sanitization

I am using https://node-postgres.com/ to write a fairly simple application, but I do have a complex constraint that has caused me issues. Namely, I need my SQL statement to select a schema based on user input

```
SELECT * FROM {some user value}.tableName
```

but when I attempt to parametrize this normally, I get a syntax error

`{"errorType":"error","errorMessage":"syntax error at or near \"$1\""`

Which seems to indicate that the value wasnt replaced as expected.

Is there a way to sanitize the incoming value without executing it in a query? or is there a proper way to parametrize this value in the query in a way that will execute properly?

(I would like to avoid a big library change to something like sequilize just to meet my basic needs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a great way to do this using the guts of the library! it digs into the prototype, so if this becomes a more regular thing looking into something like [pg-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format) might be a good call. But for now this works.

```
const sanitizedKey = db.Client.prototype.escapeIdentifier(incomingData.orgKey)
const result = await db.query(builder(`
        WITH policies_threatened_by_incident AS (
            select p.alert_id, p.tiv, p.distance
            from ${sanitizedKey}.wf_alert_policies_active p
...
```

shout out to the helpful contributors -> https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2295#issuecomment-664767339